# C# XNA Rectangle

Tags: c#, xna

How would I go about creating a XNA primitive Rectangle shape?

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this shape rendering code might be the best example out there,
http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/shape_rendering